# SQLGetPrivateProfileString reads Unicode characters incorrectly

Tags: c++, c, odbc

I use in `SQLGetPrivateProfileString` to read DSN parameters from `odbcinst.ini` (Registry).

But if I use characters like `UID='König'` in the DSN and call

```
SQLGetPrivateProfileString(DSN, INI_USERNAME, "", temp, sizeof(temp), ODBC_INI)
```

the variable `temp='K?nig'`

Naturally, odbc cannot connect to the data source.
How to read correct values?

Comment: What's `temp`'s type?

Comment: That is char temp[256];

Comment: It is piece of code from the old version of postgresql odbc driver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode version of the function needs to be called, which is `SQLGetPrivateProfileStringW`.
See [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/function-mapping-in-the-driver-manager?view=sql-server-2017)

> If the application is compiled with the _UNICODE #define the ODBC
>   header file will map undecorated function calls to the Unicode
>   version.

and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/unicode-applications?view=sql-server-2017)

> You can recompile an application as a Unicode application in one of two ways:
>
> - Include the Unicode #define contained in the Sqlucode.h header file in the application.
> - Compile the application with the compiler's Unicode option. (This option will be different for different compilers.)

See *odbcinst.h*:

```
#ifdef  UNICODE
...
#define  SQLGetPrivateProfileString     SQLGetPrivateProfileStringW
...
```

where `SQLGetPrivateProfileStringW` is declared as:

```
int  INSTAPI SQLGetPrivateProfileStringW
(
    _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpszSection,
    _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpszEntry,
    _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpszDefault,
    _Out_writes_opt_(cchRetBuffer) LPWSTR lpszRetBuffer,
    int              cchRetBuffer,
    _In_opt_ LPCWSTR lpszFilename
);
```

The Unicode version of the function recevies `LPCWSTR` and `LPWSTR`, which are pointers to a string of 16-bit Unicode characters. Whatever other function will receive those values will also need to be the Unicode version.

Comment: To test quickly I have changed the SQLGetPrivateProfileString to SQLGetPrivateProfileStringW with the same parameters. But it returns empty string.

Comment: How do you check if it is empty? In a Unicode string any one byte can be \0, each character will be represented as 2 bytes, because ODBC uses UCS-2. so you cannot expect your char array to be null terminated.

Comment: I see in the VS debugger temp=""

Comment: This just indicates that the first byte is 0

Comment: I have checked : the first 5 bytes =0, then some character, then again many zeroes....

Comment: And what did the function return? It is supposed to return the number of read characters. You can check for errors using `SQLInstallerError `.

I assume that other arguments you passed to the function might need conversion to Unicode UCS_2 encoding.

Comment: There is in v11 (line 600) https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=psqlodbc.git;a=blob;f=dlg_specific.c;h=309b9bcd546c95aeecf1fa1084a942f0117ddbee;hb=HEAD  It works in both cases: ANSI and UNICODE. And no any additional conversions